# Filter by array item or empty array

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to filter by an array that must be either empty or contain the item `1`.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "memberOrganizationFamilyIds": [
                  1
                ]
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": [
            {
              "exists": {
                "field": "memberOrganizationFamilyIds"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

According to the docs this is how it should be but it isn't working.

If we apply the first filter it works.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "memberOrganizationFamilyIds": [
                  1
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If we apply the second filter it also works.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": [
            {
              "exists": {
                "field": "memberOrganizationFamilyIds"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But not together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to filter by an array that must be either empty **or** contain the item 1

Try this you should add `should` (meaning) `or`

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "memberOrganizationFamilyIds": [
                  1
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "must_not": [
                  {
                    "exists": {
                      "field": "memberOrganizationFamilyIds"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```